# Silverlight access Azure Table REST - clientaccesspolicy.xml?

Tags: silverlight, azure, azure-table-storage, clientaccesspolicy.xml

Is it possible to have a Silverlight client app directly access the Azure Table service REST endpoints? Putting aside concerns about how to sign the requests without leaking the shared access key, Silverlight won't access the Table endpoint because neither clientaccesspolicy.xml nor crossdomain.xml are present at the root of the Table URI.

Is there any way around this aside from proxying all of the data through my web server, or running OOB with elevated permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Steve Marx in May 2010 this is not possible for Queue and Table storage:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/b95bf8e8-f718-4e3d-8eae-00fbd87ce7a2#905ad47c-ed90-4418-b9e3-9a183fb18bb8

Answer (score 0):

You create the clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml files and put them in the special [$root container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee395424.aspx) in Azure storage.  You'll then be able to access the storage successfully.

Comment: That works for Blob storage - yes. The question is for Table storage.